# STM32 uart forwarding

Tags: stm32, uart

I need to link two UARTs. Each byte received by one of them is sent to the other and vice-versa. Both have the same baud rate 9600 and configuration. If I send some characters to uart 1 via putty I can see that the data is available at ***byte*** but but its not send to uart 2?

any feedback or suggestions are appreciated

```
void HAL_UART_RxHalfCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  /* Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning */
  UNUSED(huart);

  /* NOTE: This function should not be modified, when the callback is needed,
           the HAL_UART_RxHalfCpltCallback can be implemented in the user file.
   */
    
        // USART_ISR_RXNE  = Read Data Register Not Empty 
        // USART_CR1_TXEIE = TXE Interrupt Enable 
    
    
        // uart 1 
        if(huart == &huart1){
            if (USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE){
                    byte = USART1->RDR;
                    USART2->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TXEIE;
            }
            if ((USART1->CR1 & USART_CR1_TXEIE) &&  (USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE)){
                    USART1->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_TXEIE;
                    USART1->RDR = byte2;
            }
        }
        // uart 2 
        if(huart == &huart2){
            if (USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE){
                    byte2 = USART2->RDR;
                    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TXEIE;
            }
            if ((USART2->CR1 & USART_CR1_TXEIE) &&  (USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE)){
                    USART2->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_TXEIE;
                    USART2->RDR = byte;
            }
        }

}
```

I think I have it working outside the transfer callbacks now. but still very much interested in old attempted

```
volatile uint8_t byte = '\0';
volatile uint8_t byte2 = '\0';


int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
    
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
        
    
  while (1)
  {
                if (USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE){
                    while (!(USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE) ){
                    __NOP();
                    };
                    byte = USART1->RDR;

                    USART2->TDR = byte;
                    while (!(USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_TXE)){
                    __NOP();
                    };  
                }
                    
                if (USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE){
                    while (!(USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE) ){
                    __NOP();
                    };
                    byte2 = USART2->RDR;

                    USART1->TDR = byte2;
                    while (!(USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_TXE)){
                    __NOP();
                    };
            }
  }
    
}
```

Comment: At what point are you actually sending byte?
From what I can see, you only set byte's value, but never use it  to send. 
byte is used as a value if callback is made from uart2, but it won't happen, as uart1 is the caller.